# Symfony compiler pass: I want to add method call to Logger service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, monolog, symfony-2.8

I want to add a method call (function setTimezone) to Logger service.

here is a function: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/1.x/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L696

Then how can i do that?

I want to set UTC timezone every time inject that service.

I have tried

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $logger = $container->getDefinition('goobing_core.logging.logger');
    $logger->addMethodCall('setTimezone', [new \DateTimeZone('UTC')]);
}
```

RuntimeException in XmlDumper.php line 375:
Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$utcTimeDefinition = new Definition(\DateTimeZone::class, ['UTC']);
$logger = $container->getDefinition('goobing_core.logging.logger');
$logger->addMethodCall('setTimezone', [$utcTimeDefinition]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do that with the `build` method in you bundle file, see documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $logger = $container->getDefinition('logger');
//        $logger->addMethodCall('setTimezone', [new \DateTimeZone('UTC')]);
    }  RuntimeException in XmlDumper.php line 375:
Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.

Comment: I have write my code in question. Can you guide more? Thanks.